# using kdl_parser_py

Tags: ros, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I've created a ros package with kdl_parser_py dependency. Now when I do catkin_make I get the following results:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/kdl_parser_py/cmake/kdl_parser_pyConfig.cmake:141 (message):
  Project 'flax_assist' tried to find library 'kdl_parser_py'.  The library
  is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
  'kdl_parser_py'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory
  containing its code is included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  flax_assist/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

But I'm sure kdl_parser_py is installed and `rospack find kdl_parser_py` works.
How to use it then?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253713/using-kdl_parser_py/) by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Python dependencies are *runtime* dependencies only, so they should not be listed in your `find_package(catkin COMPONENTS ..)` call in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

See [catkin documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) for how to declare and resolve Python dependencies in Catkin packages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2